# Using "this" as parameter in an existing Javascript function called by jQuery.on() event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, event-handling, jquery-events

**Problem:**

I have some `selects` with `options` in my HTML code and I have set an `on change event handler`, to figure out, when a selection will be changed.

The following code shows the jQuery code to get the on change:

```
 $(document).on('change', '.anyHtmlSelect', updateState);
```

I have an existing Javascript function, that should be used as callback function.

The Javascript function looks like:

```
function updateState(element) 
{  
    var currentId = element.attr("id");
}
```

**Question:**

How can I get the **changed** `select` as `element`?

I have tried the following:

```
 $(document).on('change', '.anyHtmlSelect', updateState($(this));
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first argument that is automatically passed to an event handler is a reference to the event itself, not the element that caused the event. To access the DOM element that triggered the event, use `this`:

Simply change:

```
function updateState(element) 
{  
    var currentId = element.attr("id");
}
```

to:

```
function updateState(event) {  
    var currentId = this.attr("id");
}
```

Comment: I think `event` might be a reserved keyword btw (or defined on `window` maybe), might not want to use it as a function argument

Comment: @simnys It is a property of `window` but this is perfectly acceptable. It's called variable "hiding" or "shadowing" and doesn't erase the global reference. It just means that for the duration of the function's scope `event` will refer to the passed argument. If you needed to access the global version, you'd simply write `window.event`. This is a powerful language feature, not something to avoid.

Comment: Yes I know, I guess it's personal preference. It would be very uncommon to access `window.event` (without specifying you want the `window` version) inside that function anyway.

Comment: Actually it wouldn't because in older versions of IE, `window.event` is the  *only* way to access the event object. It shouldn't be avoided due to preference because its a fundamental feature of the language - - lexical scope. That would be like avoiding `if` statements because of preference. Shadowing (scope) is there to be leveraged.

Answer (score 0):

After some research I have found a solution I would share with you.

In my solution, I created an **anonymous function**, which calls the `updateState` function with `$(this)` as parameter.

```
$(document).on('change', '.anyHtmlSelect', function () {
    updateState($(this));
});
```

Is there a better solution?

Comment: See my answer below for a simpler solution with explanation.

Comment: Your edit of my answer was rejected because it removes the correct code and the explanation. The argument `event` was intentionally changed to reflect the fact that this is what you will receive.